# optional parameter must be a reference type MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been working on a MVC4 C# App and send via link a value to a controller this way

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new { Id = @ViewBag.id})">@ViewBag.option2</a>
```

and works just fine but now I need to send three values via the same link to the same controller and have verified the values are not null

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new { Id = @ViewBag.id, Id2 = @ViewBag.grupo, Id3 = @ViewBag.correlativo })">@ViewBag.option2</a>
```

but get the next error

> Message = The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'grupo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ModificarOrdenInicioFormulario(System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'GFC_Site.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

this is the action in my Home controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string Id, Int32 grupo, Int32 correlativo)
```

and this is my RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); 
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

could you please tell me what to add or where the error is?

Comment: Are you sure you have valid values in `ViewBag.grupo`  and `ViewBag.correlativo` ?

Comment: yes, there are valid values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is generating the href attribute value for the link like this

```
Home/MyAction/10?id2=123&id3=456
```

But your action method parameters are `Id`, `grupo` and `correlativo`.

Your action method parameter name **should match** with your route value dictionary keys.

Use `grupo` and `correlativo` as the route value item keys instead of `id2` and `id3`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", 
         new { Id = @ViewBag.id, 
               grupo = @ViewBag.grupo, 
               correlativo = @ViewBag.correlativo })">@ViewBag.option2</a>
```

This will generate the `href` attribute value like this, which has the proper querystring keys matching with the action methor parameter name

```
Home/MyAction/10?grupo=123&correlativo=456
```

This should work, assuming your ViewBag items has valid (non null)numeric values set to it. If those could be null, consider changing your action method parameter from `int` to nullable int (`int?`)

The route value `10` in the url will be automatically mapped to the parameter named `Id` because we defined that in the default route pattern registered in the `RegisterRoutes` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home", new 
                                           { 
                                             Id = @ViewBag.id, 
                                             grupo = @ViewBag.grupo, 
                                             correlativo = @ViewBag.correlativo 
                                            })">@ViewBag.option2</a>
```

Your parameter name must be same.To handle null case s you can change your action signature as `public ActionResult MyAction(string Id, Int32? grupo, Int32? correlativo)`